# Trouble listing files with fs.readdir() in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I'm working my way through the "[Learn You The Node.js For Much Win!](https://github.com/rvagg/learnyounode)" workshop but I'm having trouble on exercise 5. It asks you to `Create a program that prints a list of files in a given directory, filtered by the extension of the files.`

I passed in the directory, `files`, that contains an assortment of JavaScript, Ruby, and plain text files. It is supposed to `console.log()` each file with the `.js` extension.

```
var fs = require('fs');

function indexDirectory(directory) {
  fs.readdir(directory, function(err, files) {
    for (var i in files) {
      if (i.indexOf('.js') != -1) {
        console.log(files[i]);
      }
    }
  });
}

indexDirectory('files');
```

My current code does not output anything when I run it with `node program.js`. Am I missing some asynchronous principle? Am I using callbacks incorrectly? Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: A `for in` loop iterates over keys, not values; don’t use it on arrays. `files.forEach(function (i) { … })`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea.

Comment: `for (var i = 0, file; i < files.length; i++) { file = files[i]}` || `files.forEach(function (file) {});` || `files.filter(function(file){ return FILE_IS_JS; });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`files` are array, you should use `forEach` instead of `for .. in`

```
var fs = require('fs');

function indexDirectory(directory) {
  fs.readdir(directory, function(err, files) {
    files.forEach(function (file) {
      if (file.indexOf('.js') != -1) {
        console.log(file);
      }
    });  
  });
}

indexDirectory('files');
```

Answer (score 0):

One more problem with this code is that it will print also files with '.json' extension. So instead of indexOf you should use, for example, regular expressions. Something like this:

```
var matches = new RegExp(".js$").test(files[i]);
if (matches) {
   console.log(files[i]);
}
```